# #load "unix.cma" causes syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I'm trying to compile / run in interpreter a program written by another programmer. This program uses this construct:

```
#load "unix.cma"
```

which I haven't encountered before. I've found this page: http://ocamlunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/generalities.html which mentions it, but typing this code into interpreter results in syntax error. Same thing happens when I run the file with this instruction through `ocamlc`. What am I missing?

```
ocamlc -v
The Objective Caml compiler, version 3.12.1
Standard library directory: /usr/lib64/ocaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#load` is a toplevel directive, which is not available in `ocamlc` nor `ocamlopt` compilers but only in OCaml toplevel (REPL) `ocaml`. See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual023.html#toc91. Use the toplevel to run the program:

```
ocaml blahblah.ml
```

Comment: The weird issue I was having with it when (I actually did try running it in `ocaml` REPL) was that it was missing the end-of-block delimiter (the `;;`) and I had to run it by passing the name of the file to `ocaml` rather than trying to evaluate the buffer with OCaml code...